# solder/join single copper filament to contacts (speaker tweeter)

Tags: soldering, speakers

As a result of the careful shipping of UPS, my speakers arrived with broken tweeters. One tweeter in particular has had its connections severed when the plastic support broke. I need to re-connect the filaments.

In this picture the two single filaments coming out of the tweeter are visible.
[image]

Those filaments need to be connected back to the contacts' plate that broke off (the plastic plate itself has since been reattached with glue):

[image]

There is about 1 cm gap from when the filaments are broken to the metal connection on the plate.
I have been told that the filaments were covered in enamel, and to scrape it off with a scalpel. I tried, as best as I could; hopefully I managed to remove the enamel but I am not sure. The filaments are so small I am worried they would break if I scrape more.
I have a small soldering iron, like this: https://www.clasohlson.com/no/Cocraft-loddepenn-HS-30L/p/41-1364

What would be the best way to do this now:

1. Bridge the filaments to the metal connections using a filament from electrical wire
2. Bridge it by making a strip of soldering tin
3. other suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: I would go for option 1. Option 2 is bad. I have no further suggestions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other: Rebuild the broken terminal piece, but place it closer to the existing wire ends. I guess you can fasten it well with epoxy. Solder the existing wire ends. Insert a couple of drops of some acid free permanently soft silicone material which dampen vibrations so that your new soldering joints do not enjoy any bending which could come along the wires.

The thickness of the dampening material around the filaments should grow slowly and gradually towards the soldered area to be effective.

Comment: Thank you, I went with your suggestion and I was able to repair the tweeter. It was a good strategy indeed!

Now the speaker woks nicely. The only "issue" I am noticing, is that it sounds quite "lower" than the the other speaker in the pair, which was not broken. Using the amplifier's settings I have to increase the repaired speaker level by 4 decibel in order for the two to be balanced. Do you have any suggestion why that might be happening?

Comment: If it was broken also elsewhere than at the connector it's possible that the parts are not any more exactly in their places. Are you sure you have not increased the mass of moving parts when fixing? Strong shock also weakens the magnet. The magnet can have a crack.

Comment: It might be that with the impacts it got a little damaged. Hard to verify. Thank you for the inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Studying your photo, it looks like 3 of the 4 support arms that position the tweeter in the housing have broken. Even if you glue them back, I think the tweeter will rub and rattle with strong sounds. Instead of a frustrating battle to solder those wires, you should replace the tweeter unit. Before you do anything, file a damage claim including your photos.

Comment: Correct, the tweeter broke off from the housing horn as well. I have reattached it using a glue that's stated to hold 1 tonn per square cm, so I hope that would be enough (even though it's only a 1-component glue).
The story with UPS is a total nightmare, but to cut it short, I did file a complain but they deny any damage. They actually said to the shipper that I refused delivery and they would either send the speakers back or destroy them. Stay away from UPS guys...
I got them back, but the tweeter unit is not in production anymore so I have to repair it or change the speakers.